# "either or" functionality in sql query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, ignite

Question is regarding ignite-jdbc.

```
create table Student(id number pk,name varchar2);
```

Can some body tell me how query a this in MySQL in such a way that it satisfy the below conditions on column name .

1. It should have "either or " kind of thing.
2. It can select either the given value or any value.

I am working on some search related query so I was looking for a query such that if parameter name is not null then select only those record with the given name

or

if parameter name is null then select all records.

I need this query in jdbc preparedStatement.

ex :

```
String s = "select * from students where name is either ? or all "
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? Don't use inappropriate tags.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you show an sample input and desired result?

Comment: @Barmar : I am just using an example to get help from you guys.Its not my homework.

Comment: Its now only sql tag.

Comment: It would be best if you tagged with the actual database you're using, since the best solution often depends on which.

Comment: You still need to clarify the question. If you want to select the given value or any value, what's the point of the given value, just select everything.

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) And sample data and desired results would definitely help a lot here.

Comment: If you want to select everything if the given value is null, you can use `WHERE @given IS NULL OR colname = @given`

Comment: question updated with correct database tag.

Comment: I haven't worked with JDBC, but if you're preparing the query in any programming language it's obviously easier to do just that, use the programming language to prepare exactly the query you want to execute. In simple terms, use an `if` statement to create a query with or without the `where` clause.

Comment: @downernn i also think that this is the only way( using if else in java).